# Converting seconds to minutes using datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I am having trouble understanding a simple timedelta function.

In the code below, it is supposed to convert total_travel_time provided in seconds to minutes. Can someone briefly explain the logic behind the (seconds = total_travel_time) part?
Is it telling python that the total_travel_time is in seconds?
How come python understands to convert it to minutes even without "minutes" somewhere in the code?

```
total_travel_time = df['Trip Duration'].sum()
print("Total travel time: {}".format(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_travel_time))))
```

Comment: `class datetime.timedelta`
A duration expressing the difference between two date, time, or datetime instances to microsecond resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some parts that aren't really relevant to your question.

It boils down to this:

```
import datetime

n = 120
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=n))
```

Note that even the `str()` bit is superfluous, since passing it to `print()` already requires conversion to string anyway

Result:

```
0:02:00
```

It's not converting anything to minutes, it's constructing a `timedelta` object,  being given a number of seconds. In this case, that happens to include a number of minutes. But depending on the number of seconds, it could be anything.

When printing a `timedelta`, Python needs to turn it into a string of characters (because that's all we can read) and it chooses the standard HH:mm:ss format (unless it's more than a day, then it'll print the number of days separately).

To get the actual number of minutes, you'd actually start with the seconds (that are accessible directly on the `timedelta` object):

```
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=n).seconds // 60)
```

Comment: `>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=600000))` Output:
`'6 days, 22:40:00'`

Comment: @AKMalkadi, indeed - what is your point?

Comment: my point is to show that it is not about only minutes

Comment: As evidenced by "constructing a timedelta object" and "the standard HH:mm:ss format (unless it's more than a day, then it'll print the number of days separately)" - I was wondering why you were repeating a point that was already made in the answer. You're welcome to of course, just seemed a bit odd. Not sure why you would think the answer suggests "it is [..] about only minutes". Perhaps you meant to comment on the question and not the answer?